# Trigger on Account to calculate sum of amount

Tags: trigger

In the annual revenue field on account, we want to get the sum of all the opportunities 
amount which are closed won and if the annual revenue is already generated in the account 
than the trigger won't work.

Comment: did not my last answer work?

Comment: actually no !! Here is what I wanted
set<string> setIds = new set<string>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.New)
    {
        setIds.add(acc.id); 
    }
    List<Opportunity> opps = [Select Id, amount from Opportunity where id in : setIds]; 
    Map<Id, List<Opportunity> > accountIdOppsMap = new Map<Id, List<Opportunity>>();
 for( Opportunity opp : opps) 
    {
     if(accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid) == null) 
     {
      accountIdOppsMap.put(opp.accountid, new List<Opportunity>());
     }
     accountIdOppsMap.get(opp.accountid).add(opp);
 }

Comment: could you edit your question? I think it's a bit unclear. Reading what you wrote, I understand you simply need (made with code) the rollup functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement could be accomplished by simply setting up a Roll-up Summaru field on Account, filtering the opportunities to be computed in the calculation so that only the closed ones (eventually also filtering only the ones that are closed in the current year) will be considered.

Comment: I want trigger as i dont want RUp

Comment: Would you like to have the field always up to date , or updated only once a year?

Comment: !! I wanted it to be always

Answer (score 0):

Give A try like below

```
trigger SumAccountAmount on Account (before insert,before update)
{

    set<string> setIds = new set<string>();
    for(Account acc : Trigger.New)
    {
        setIds.add(acc.id); 
    }

    AggregateResult[] accList = [SELECT AVG(Amount)aver,AccountId FROM Opportunity where accountid in :setIds and IsWon = TRUE group by accountid ];
    Object avgAmount ;
    for(AggregateResult sobj : accList)
    {   
        avgAmount =accList[0].get('aver');
    }
    for(Account acc : Trigger.New)
    {
       acc.AnnualRevenue = (Decimal)avgAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: This trigger fires on Account, and it does not track change on opportunities, that is the object that has to fire changes in Account's annual revenue.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick :

```
 trigger updateAnnualRevenue on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    List<Id> toUpdate = new List<Id>();
    List <Account> toUpdateDML = new List<Account>();
    Map<Account,List<Opportunity>> accToOpp = new map <Account,List<Opportunity>>();
    public Decimal annualrevenue;

    for(Opportunity o : trigger.new) {
        if(o.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
        toUpdate.add(o.AccountId);
        }
    }
    for(Account a : [SELECT Id,AnnualRevenue,(SELECT ID,Amount,StageName FROM Opportunities) from Account WHERE Id IN : toUpdate]) {
        accToOpp.put (a, a.Opportunities);
        annualrevenue=0;
        for(Opportunity ooo : accToOpp.get(a)) {
            if(ooo.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
            annualrevenue= annualrevenue + ooo.Amount;
            }
        }
        a.AnnualRevenue = annualrevenue;
        toUpdateDML.add(a);
    }       
    update toUpdateDML; 
}
```